# How do I get a webpack bundled files to run?

Tags: symfony, webpack

I have several JavaScript files created via Webpack. Besides the general `app.js` I also have JavaScript files that are only used on certain pages. After the build process, I have included the new JavaScript file included. **The JS file is also loaded successfully**.  But the JavaScript does not run.

What do I have to do to make it work? Or am I already doing something wrong?

**Goal** run my `build/myjs.js` file and print `console.log('Hello world!');`

`webpack.config.js`

```js
Encore
  // …
  .addEntry('app', './assets/app.js')
  .addEntry('myjs', './assets/scripts/my.js')
  // …
```

`build/myjs.js`

```js
(self["webpackChunk"] = self["webpackChunk"] || []).push([["myjs"],{

/***/ "./assets/scripts/myjs.js":
/*!********************************!*\
  !*** ./assets/scripts/myjs.js ***!
  \********************************/
/***/ ((__unused_webpack_module, __unused_webpack_exports, __webpack_require__)
=> {

__webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.array.for-each.js */
"./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.for-each.js");

__webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js */
"./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.object.to-string.js");

__webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each.js */
"./node_modules/core-js/modules/web.dom-collections.for-each.js");

__webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.array.concat.js */
"./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.array.concat.js");

__webpack_require__(/*! core-js/modules/es.promise.js */
"./node_modules/core-js/modules/es.promise.js");

console.log('Hello world!');
// ...
```

My `show.html.twig` file where I need the special JavaScript:

```
{% extends 'test/base.html.twig' %}
{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script src="{{ asset('build/myjs.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have add in your twig file the `encore_entry_script_tags()` helpers function. As parameter you pass the name of the file which you want to include. In your case `myjs`.

The same you have to do with CSS files. But then use the `encore_entry_link_tags()` helper function. With the name from the file as parameter. Dont forget to use addStyleEntry('targetName',source).

Answer (score 1):

You just need to use `encore_entry_script_tags` function, as shown [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/frontend/encore/split-chunks.html).

In your case, it would be something like:

```
{% extends 'test/base.html.twig' %}
{{ encore_entry_script_tags('myjs') }}
```

The file will be loaded automatically, and as any JS file will be executed when loaded.